# Linux backup script won't run

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

I am using limux CentOS7 to run a backup script that will create a .tar file and then send the file to an S3 bucket.

However when the cornjob is executed, it only runs half of the script and creates the .tar file but does not upload it to S3.

The backup script;

```
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`            # This Command will add date in Backup File Nam            e.
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz     #define Backup file name format.
SRCDIR=/opt                      # Location of Important Data Directory (Source of             backup).
DESDIR=/home/centos/backupfile   # Destination of backup file.
tar -cvf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
aws s3 cp /home/centos/backupfile/$FILENAME s3://backup/
```

The cronjob is;

```
30 7 * * * /home/centos/backupfile/runbackup
```

When I run the back up file manually by running ./runbackup it works fine and sends the file to an s3 bucket.

I have checked permissions of the .tar file and it all looks fine, not too sure why it wont work. I have tried moving the file locations, changing the cronjob settings but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to specify the user who executes the command? Like this:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
30 7 * * * root /home/centos/backupfile/runbackup
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your bucket isn't actually named "backup".

When you run it manually, under which user do you run it? Is it the same as the user that runs it under cron? Also, are you sourcing the profile of that user too (`source ~/.profile` or similar)? If not, you may be missing some environment variables which are needed for the script which are present when you run it interactively. Another thing to check is how you are passing credentials to S3? For example, when you run it manually, does that user have AWS credentials and profile et al or are you using an IAM role?

And finally, ensuring that the paths to executables in your script at valid; e.g. `/usr/local/bin/aws`.

One way of debugging it is writing a bunch of logging statements to a file so that you can inspect a little more what is occurring.

Comment: Different bucket name. I run it as centos not root. AWS creds are stored when I configured aws cli.

Comment: error message /home/centos/backupfile/runbackup: line 6: aws: command not found.

Comment: What about entering the full path to your aws executable?

Comment: ok so I declared the user as centos in the cronjob; 30 7 * * * centos /home/centos/backupfile/runbackup. Now get the following error /bin/sh: centos: command not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160624/discussion-between-smcstewart-and-user3013325).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the keys as environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (your AWS access key) and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY (your AWS secret key) in the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered yesterday with the help of (smscstewart).

We added the below lines which worked fine.

*source $HOME/.bash_profile
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp /home/centos/backupfile/$FILENAME s3://backup/*